# How do you exit the game?

Tags: astroneer

So far, I know you can exit the game when you are playing (on a World) but I can not find the way to exit it (other than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) when being on the **Menu**, is there anything?

*Pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> returns nothing.*

Answer (score 2):

Press `F6`. This brings up the same dialog you see in-game from which you can "quit to desktop."